# PDO PHP Missing Record Sets from Stored Routine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a stored routine which is 3 selects.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Wibble > 0;
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Dibble > 1;
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE Fibble > 2;
```

When I run this in MySQL WorkBench, I get 3 recordsets returned.

This is not code below, but this site forces me to put it in as code:

```
Table1 = 3 rows.
Table2 = 0 rows.
Table3 = 5 rows.
```

When I loop through the recordsets in PHP though, I only get 2!

```
$returnedRows1 = $results->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$results->nextRowset( );
$returnedRows2 = $results->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$results->nextRowset( );
$returnedRows3 = $results->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

This basically gives you:

```
PDOStatement::fetchAll(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in
```

As the record set from Table2 has been lost in translation.

Thus $returnedRows1 has results from Table1.

Thus $returnedRows2 has results from Table3.

And finally $returnedRows3 errors.

So... any ideas how to get PDO to return the record set regardless of whether it has zero rows or not?

Comment: What code are you using to loop through the recordsets? You need to include some code for the MySQL and PHP side if you want anyone to look at this issue and try to reproduce it.

Comment: To be honest, it was basically exactly as I had it above. The loop etc. itself wasn't the issue. Problem is, that was 11 months ago and having messed around with it for an hour or two tonight, I can't replicate it. So for now, you may need to ask the guy below for example code as he currently has the issue.

Comment: Ha, didn't even notice it was so old. Just came up on the queue because of the new answer.

Answer (score -1):

I too see this problem.  I originally thought it was related to the statement->nextrowset() bug (#67130) which is fixed as of PHP 5.6, however I have upgraded, and I still see the issue.

In my case, I am doing FETCH_OBJ, and interestingly, I can get results back if I use bindParam instead of bindValue on the inbound parameters.  but I haven't nailed it down past that.

In addition to what you are seeing, it appears that if a ddl statement is executed in the stored procedure (like optimize table) then all rowsets after that point are lost from the result set.

Are you and I the only people in the universe to use the PDO with stored procedures that return multiple result sets?

In your specific case, (I haven't tried this myself) you might try FETCH_OBJ, then the rowset won't be empty, it will have a property with the value of 0.